# Sort rows from DB paginated using spring JPA based on calculated value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I retrieved a list of rows from DB paginated using spring JPA. in code, I calculated a value for each row, It's requested to be displayed sorted by this calculated value.
I used compareTo() method to sort based on this calculated value, my problem here is I can't sort the whole results it's only on the current page, so if the user requests the next page it contains rows with values less than the prev page, I need to display the rows sorted by this calculated value with pagination

What I'm supposed to do is moving the logic of the calculated value to DB so I could query this value sorted but this solution will take a lot of time to do, any suggestions? , thanks.

Comment: Please enter some sample code to help answer.